# Editing of django form with primary key fields

Tags: django

I have a django model form for which I allowed partial form save since its a long form. Now I want the user to come back and complete the form later.

There is one hindrance however that my database cannot accept duplicate entries with same primary key. So should I remove primary key in my database to solve this or is there another way to make it possible? Suggestions please.

Answer (score 0):

Why not keep only one row per user for that form? Just add one boolean field to check whether the form is submitted or is a draft. Something like `is_submitted=models.Boolean(default=False)`. Keep updating the row with the new values on each partial save (a separate button for `Save` or an AJAX call for auto save).

When the form is submitted, just mark the field `is_submitted = True` and perform whatever actions you want after that.